# Fluent NHibernate set all IDs to assigned

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I know I can manually set each Id property to assigned using `Assigned()`.

Is there any way of applying this globally, as I want to do it on every entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just register [FluentNHibernate convention](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions) like this:

```
public class AssignedIdConvention : IIdConvention
{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.GeneratedBy.Assigned();
    }
}
```

Registration goes like this:

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Mappings(...)
    .Conventions.Add<AssignedIdConvention>()
```